# Buttons well displayed in IB but not in simulator

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm adjusting buttons like this in IB:

[image: IB 1]
However, when running I have this(B is in above A) :

[image]

When I disable auto layout, I have the expected results, however, I'm having other problems with other views. Is there any solution other than disabling auto layout?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your constraints are the problem. Try to get rid of constraints that are making the button aligned from the bottom. Then apply the 3.5 form factor in the IB to see if it works. Just ask if you need more clarification.

**Edit:** A tip is that if you can't delete the constraints from the menu, you can go to the document outline and manually delete it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So iPhone 5 users will not have the same view as iPhone 4 users :/ ?

Comment: same view, but different constraints attribute

Comment: Right. So all that would have to happen is to go to the constraints and find and delete constraints that are setting space from the bottom of the view. This is better than completely disabling auto layout and it's something that needs to be learned. This problem happens a lot with multiple labels, text fields, and buttons.

Comment: When I change the position of the B button it's changed too in both 4 and 3.5 screens(and that's normal). And how I can't find how to delete a constraint, I want to delete the one related with the button of the screen.

Comment: The B button should change, but the overlapping happens when a set amount of space is set, but it pushes the B button to far up when the 3.5 screen is called. The constraints would be in the document outline (on the left). It looks like this: http://www.techotopia.com/images/f/f6/Iphone_ios6_document_outline_constraints.png

Comment: @ShaanSingh well, your answer is quite similar to me.

Comment: Yes I suppose it is, but I tried to give more detail. Remember, the important part is that the user gets the answer they need

Answer (score 2):

Check if Auto Layout is enabled.

If Interface Builder is using 3.5" layout, and your simulator is iPhone 5 ( 4" layout ), you have to adjust the Auto Layout constraints to fit the 4" layout.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, I'm working now on iPhone 5 (Retina 4-inch simulator), I was on Retina 3.5-inch simulator. But, do you advice me to work with 3.5 or 4? And how can I ensure the best compatibility between 4 and 3.5 ?

Comment: There is a button on the IB's right bottom corner to switch between 3.5" and 4" layout

Comment: The button that's in the bottom right hand corner is the left most button in this section.

Comment: So I switch between the layouts and see if there is something wrong and fix it(remembers me of Android :( )

Comment: If I change button position on 3.5 it's changed too in 4, so same problem, fixing it here will mess it in the other side.

Comment: See my comment under my answer. If you still don't understand, just ask and I can make you a sample project or something.